# Query to get a field to field logic from source to target using informatica repository tables

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I would like to get a query for source to target field flow using informatica repository tables like for example the repository view : REP_MAPPING_CONN_PORTS.

We do not have any additional licensing for the Metadata Manager. Idea is to basically automate the end to end source to target logical flow of all fields in a mapping. Say after every release, a job runs which automatically updates the logical flow, which would then be very easy for any person to go through and understand the logic.

say something like if i have a mapping m_temp, with say 4 transformations :

Source --> Source Qualifier --> Expression --> Target

I need to extract the data from the repository say something like below, so that i can then showcase it in a front end tool of some sort.

Say in the above mapping, FIELD_1 starts from the Source flowing though SQ and there is a logical IF in the expression which then is connected to a field FIELD_2 in the Target. This is how i expect the output of the query to be.

From                   Logic                            TO

FIELD_1           IF(FIELD_1='1','A','B')                    FIELD_2

Could someone please assist me on a query that i could use to run on the informatica Repository?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool that I'm using: https://xmlanalyzer.maciejg.pl

It does generate a documentation based on XML exports, not on repository. And it shows the basic data lineage, without full logic. Trying to put all the expressions, aggregation conditions, lookups, joins etc. would make this huge and unreadable, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Well, actually this would be a manual task. The main intention of doing this would be automation. So that when there is a change in logic, or say we add new fields in the mapping flow, if we just execute a workflow, it should be able to update this new information.

Comment: But now that you mentioned about it, I am thinking whether its still possible to automate it, in some way by exporting it into an XML, and in some way automatically get the source to target transformation at every column level.